# Changing div values when dropdown is selected

Tags: jquery, json

I have a Jquery drop-down, values are fetched inside a text box and a div..

when the **first drop-down** is selected values in both text-box and div changes... but when i choose **second, third and fourth drop-down option**.. values in text-box changes but the values inside **div doesn't change**..  Here is the fiddle on which I am working

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/binoymat/d9f8t9vj/5/][1]
```

where am I going wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line that do the changes in the div is `$("#totalVisitors").text(total);`. This line is in the `$("#category").on('change', function () {` event so it's works only when the first combo is changing.

I'm not sure what you want to do, but if you just want to show the save value in the input `Visitors:` and in the div `TOTAL VISITORS FOR THE DAY` so you need to add the line in the rest `change` event:

```
$("select[id^='category']:not(#category)").on('change', function () {
    var dept_number = parseInt($(this).val());
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
    $('#dept-input').val(dept_number);
    $('#price-input').val(price);
    // Add this line
    $("#totalVisitors").text(price);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d9f8t9vj/7/

Comment: Would it be possible to edit the fiddle for the second, third and fourth drop-down to change its values inside the div???

Comment: Why do you have `$("#category").on('change', function () {` and `$("select[id^='category']:not(#category)")`? Why didn't you use just the second? What is the difference between the first combo and the rest combos? Just the trigger of the `change` event?

Comment: $("#category").on('change', function () {   is used to call the first dropdown.. On change of it the rest of the drop-down works.. $("select[id^='category']:not(#category)").. is used to to just change the value in the text box... like u mentioned.. just the change event

Comment: $("#totalVisitors").text(price); "price" was the keyword i was missing... well,, thanks @Mosh Feu... that is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck!